# passenger + apache on ubuntu 12 strange behaviour with SHH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, passenger

I have ubuntu 12.10 server with rvm + rails + passenger + apache installed. I have a strange problem: When I am on ssh session via putty on windows, the application is working normally. After I close the session, I get 403 Forbidden error! Same happened with nginx, however I was getting a 404 error. I don't know how opening ssh is related to this. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you aren't running the apache (or whatever server is actually running the code) service in the background and once you kill the ssh session it is killing the terminal and your service is only running on that terminal?

Comment: No, because apache is still running after closing SSH. It just give me a 403 forbidden error